# Php unit test with redis has segmentation fault

Tags: laravel, redis, phpunit, php-8, laravel-jobs

Recently I bought a mac with an m1 chip. When I run my phpunit tests in a laravel 8 project with php8 I get this error message:

```
 80630 segmentation fault  vendor/bin/phpunit
```

It looks related to redis because only tests go wrong where redis, is used (for example jobs). My redis driver is `[phpredis][1]`.

I've got no Idea how I can fix this, it used to work on my old mac. I installed phpredis through pecl.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like there's a bug in the phpredis extension; try to create a simplified test case based on what the code's doing when it happens, and raise it as a bug.